# The LINQ expression 'x' could not be translated - querying a property of an object which is an array if integers

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework, linq

I have the following query code, trying to filter a set of results from an object which has an array of integers (years), against a minimum year and maximum year as selected by the user.

```
var query = this.db.Titles
            .Where(m => m.Votes >= this.MinimumVotes)
            .Where(m => (decimal)m.Rating >= this.MinimumRating)
            .Where(m => m.Years.Any(year => year >= this.MinYear && year <= this.MaxYear));
```

The error message is:

```
The LINQ expression 'year => (int?)year >= __MinYear_2 && (int?)year <= __MaxYear_3' could not be translated
```

I have read some of the other stack overflow questions/answers on this and understand that this is not something that can be efficiently translated. However I am struggling to come up with a LINQ statement that could be translated.

For context, this is a list of TV series, and the 'years' are the years in which seasons have been released. E.g. Breaking Bad would have { 2008, 2009, 2010 ...etc}.

If the user selects their year filter to be 2009 to 2015, I would want Breaking Bad to show up since it has seasons that were released within that window.

This all works fine for the WPF version of the app, but I am making a web version that is backed by a Postgres DB, and using EF to interact with the DB.

Comment: You can always do ToList before the last where and go clientside.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the query that you need?                                                             I mean the double 'year' expression   ".Where(m => m.Years.Any(year => year >= this.MinYear)" and not ".Where(m => m.Years.Any( year >= this.MinYear)" ?

Comment: Are `this.MinYear` and `this.MaxYear` values nullable int? How would you expect that to work?

Comment: Yes it is true that MinYear and MaxYear are nullable, that is a separate mistake. If I change it to use their actual int values, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue with the following code which appears to allow a query to be created for the DB:

```
var yearsRange = Enumerable.Range(this.MinYear.Value, this.MaxYear.Value - this.MinYear.Value + 1).ToArray();

var query = this.db.Titles
       .Where(m => m.Votes >= this.MinimumVotes)
       .Where(m => (decimal)m.Rating >= this.MinimumRating)
       .Where(m => m.Years.Any(year => yearsRange.Contains(year)));
```